# Unable to figure out licence url for mpd url?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, drm, mpeg-dash, widevine

the mpd url is
https://drvideo-ak.akamaized.net/video-sg3/53ae84d1-8b41-4323-8be9-a0fe5ddbf130/5255.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

license URL within the manifest
https://drvideo.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?kid=a09a150f-4f3b-407e-b034-54a13970202b

I think the app has a unique id which it sends to server when it asks for decryption maybe any help to crack this would be helpful

```
KEY : VALUE

Dr-Platform: android

Dr-Dv: m.2061a6e23daeed98
course-id: 1

Dr-UID: 61933ca3aa8ded2ae8069bc7 - MFREE

Dr-App: marrow

Dr-Dv-ENC: E2Hr3fbcmoaRBObXI/EtpcK5R8ZFwpC7hHh5dBXFrYQx2kVcQiR8C9Ib2tmqcxvimg==

Dr-Dv-Model: M2007J17I

Dr-Token: .eJxVztEKwjAMheF3ybVI17Da-jIlNhEKbimZzAvx3e0oCN7-fBzOG3JluEKYEmIhJIos7EmiC-lWLnACtsyy1yKdLWfvwkRBPDKJcIoDUGt5F9uqrl2hm0fW7a_-7LFEZvoapT3oeVdbeqaVTfujzxfm9DAl.FHTOIw.twxRJE_kSg78UGEr6YLHyBdywA0

Dr-App-Version: 305

Dr-Dv-Ts: 1637039334139

User-Agent: Marrow/7.14 (com.marrow; build:305; Android 11(30); Device)

Accept-Encoding: gzip

Host: drvideo-ak.akamaized.net

Connection: Keep-Alive

Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiNzgzYTc0Zjk0M2E0NDAyMGFhZTFhYTMwYTZhOWU3YmEiLCJtYWlsYm94IjoiaGFzZXJlODgxM0BjeWFkcC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzE4MTIzODB9.jQPPzNUkFOsZvqKS2OYRSblJkJS4aPBzJuZyle_dY0U
```

I am unable to extract keys despite these two
I have sniffed out this off of an app using fiddler
Any help would be appreciated.